# How to set up CORS in ASP.net Core WebAPI

Tags: cors, asp.net-core-webapi

Please advise how to solve the following problem. I have two applications: Elma 365 and a Web API. I want to make Elma 365 interact with the external API of the ASP.NET Core application. I configured the CORS policy, where I specified the Elma 365 application domain in `WithOrigins`, but I still get an error:

> Access to fetch at 'https://myApp.com/api/order/1' from origin 'https://elma365.com' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
> If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to   'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I have configured the CORS policy in my app in the following way:

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: policyName,
                      builder =>
                      {
                          builder
                            .WithOrigins("https://elma365.com") 
                            .WithMethods("GET")
                            .AllowAnyHeader();
                      });
});

app.UseCors(policyName);
```

From the Elma365 application, I access an external API using the fetch command. As a result I got the same error.

Tell me please what my mistake is?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Include the code for your fetch aswell

Answer (score 0):

> From the Elma365 application, I access an external API using the fetch
> command. As a result I got the same error.

From your description,it seems that you registed Cros in  Elma365 application,then when you  access other api,the response header would never contain `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://elma365.com"` or `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"`

The codes

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: policyName,
                      builder =>
                      {
                          builder
                            .WithOrigins("https://elma365.com") 
                            .WithMethods("GET")
                            .AllowAnyHeader();
                      });
});

app.UseCors(policyName);
```

should be in your WebApi project,it add :

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers  "*"
Access-Control-Allow-Methods  "Get"
Access-Control-Allow-Origin   "https://elma365.com"
```

to the response headers

similar with

```
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>            
{                
     context.Response.Headers.TryAdd("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 
     "*");                
      context.Response.Headers.TryAdd("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", 
     "Get");                
     context.Response.Headers.TryAdd("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", 
     "https://elma365.com");
      await next.Invoke();           
 });
```

For example,With the codes in MVC project:

```
<script>    
fetch("https://localhost:44393/api/Products/1", { method: 'Get'})        
.then(function (response) { return response.json()}) 
.then(function (json) { console.log(json) })        
.catch(error=>console.log(error.message))
</script>
```

When I modified the api's program.cs

[image]

[image]

When you fetch data from different external Apis, make sure every api's resopnse would contain the above headers